# Bootstrap 3.0 - Make link buttons stack?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <div class="btn-group">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="index.html">Mining Product1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="index.html">Mining Product2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="index.html">Mining Product3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="index.html">Mining Product4</a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="index.html">Mining Product5</a>
            </div>
</div>
```

I've made a bar of buttons using that and it works fine but when I view it on my phone all the buttons are squished with the text coming out of them. How can I make it so when the screen size is smaller the buttons collapse from a bar and stack on top of each other?

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to your group, I've used `btn-group-sm-stacked`.

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-sm-stacked">
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="#">Mining Product1</a>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="#">Mining Product2</a>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="#">Mining Product3</a>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="#">Mining Product4</a>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="#">Mining Product5</a>
</div>
```

And then use media queries to change its behaviour on small devices:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .btn-group-sm-stacked {
    display: block;
  }

  .btn-group-sm-stacked .btn {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

Check it out at [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Jk461RUAeh)

Comment: I've also removed some unnecessary `div`s you were using.